# Strange problem with line drawing on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, line, cgcontext

I have a task to draw a separator line with 2px height between UIView cells. Top 1px high line should have color #F1F1F1 and bottom 1px high line should have color  #DDDDDD
As result, on iPhone simulator with Retina display these 2 lines are seen clearly with different colors (#F1F1F1 and #DDDDDD parts), on iPad simulator - line is distorted, and there are no lines with such colors.

Code fragment used for drawing such line:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);     
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.);

CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, CGColorGetComponents(
          [[GlobalHelper colorFromHexRGB:@"#F1F1F1"] CGColor]) );

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0., line_y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, line_y );
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
CGContextSaveGState(context);     
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.);

CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, 
                  CGColorGetComponents([[GlobalHelper colorFromHexRGB:@"#DDDDDD"] CGColor]));

line_y += 1.;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0., line_y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, line_y );
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

For view object, which used as holder for drawing line (this is subclass of UITableViewCell). I tried changing parameters "opaque" and "clearsContextBeforeDrawing". Same result - on iPhone Retina all OK, for iPad - line is distorted.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

One idea: a 1-pixel wide line drawn at an integral coordinate will be blurred because half of the line will be on each side of the pixel boundary.  Try adding 0.5 to your `line_y` coordinate and see if it fixes your problem.